# how to make full width when u have a container

Tags: html, css, header, width, footer

hello guys i need help im trying to make the navigation full width but its inside the div name wrapper that has set width of 900 i cant imagine how can i do it i dont want to create another div like the header  i want a way where i can set full width of anything inside the wrapper for less coding here is the HTML. P.S please make the code easy to understand im just a newbie..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MY TITLE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="full">
            <div class="box">
                <h1>HEAD</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="list">
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>About Us</li>
                    <li>Contact Us</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

while here is the CSS

```
*{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;

}

.wrapper{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:900px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background:green;

}
.full{
    width:100%;
    background:black;

}
.box{
    text-align:center;
    color:red;
    width:500px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background:black;

    }
.list{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:500px;

    }
ul li {
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-right:30px;
   }
```

Comment: As in you want things inside the `div` with the class `wrapper` to be wider than `900px`?

Comment: Squeezing something larger than its container is possible, but it certainly isn't best practice in this case.  You do know you can have two wrappers, right?  One that is full width that contains anything that needs to be 100% width and one inside that that is only 900px.

Comment: This cannot exceed 900px as the element is under wrapper which is 900px. it will take 900px as full width, 

You can position fixed top 0. but it will always stick to top of window. and it will be 100% to window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using following css -

```
body { position: relative; }
.list { height: 35px; left: 0; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 38px; width: 100%; }
.list > ul { margin: 0 auto; max-width: 900px; padding: 7px 0; text-align: center; }
```

As you wish to keep things inside wrapper and without adding any new div, this seems a solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

try this . try to remove `width:900px;`

or make it `width: 100%;`

```css
.wrapper{
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid red;
    background:green;

}
```

Comment: This is changing the prerequisites of his question, not fixing it.

Comment: i want only a certain part in the wrapper to be full width if i were to do that all inside the wrapper would be 100% width